# Extras values after calling main method

Tags: java, methods, output, program-entry-point

This program works fine if i enter the correct value (int value). However, when I enter in a character or any other wrong value it displays the wrong input message and calls the main method again. The only problem is after calling the main method and inputting the correct input it prints out extra data why is that?

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;



public class TestPolyVal {
  public static void main(String[] args){
      int xValue = 0;
      String value = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What is the value of X");
    try{
     xValue = Integer.parseInt(value);}
    catch (NumberFormatException e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Wrong input. Please input only integer values.");

        TestPolyVal.main(args);
    }
    int[] intArray = new int[20] ;
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i ++){
      intArray[i] = 2;}

    System.out.println(calculateBruteForce(intArray,xValue));
    System.out.println("0");
    System.out.println(calculateHorner(intArray,xValue));}


static int calculateBruteForce(int[] a, int b){
    int sum = 0 ;
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i ++){
      sum +=a[i]*powerCalc(b,i);}
    return sum;}

static int powerCalc(int c, int d){
    int powerValue = c;
    if (d==0){
      powerValue = 1;}
    else if (d==1){
      powerValue = c;}
    else if (d>1){
      for (int i = 1; i<d;i++){

        powerValue = powerValue*c;}}
    return powerValue;}

static int calculateHorner(int[] e, int f){

    int acc = e[e.length-1];
    for(int i = e.length-2; i >= 0; i--){
        acc = (acc * f)+ e[i];}
    return acc;}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting extra printouts because the first `main` execution will continue after the second `main` invocation is done.

This can be fixed by adding a `return;` after the new call to `main`:

```
catch (NumberFormatException e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Wrong input. Please input only integer values.");
    TestPolyVal.main(args);
    return;
}
```

Comment: can you tell me what it return to?

Comment: It is a void method so when I return it returns nothing right?

Comment: Exactly. Since it is of type `void` you don't use any value with the `return`. It will return to wherever the method was called from. If it was the start of the program, the program will terminate.

Answer (score 0):

The approach of calling main() from within main() is not a great approach in this case. I, as an adversarial user, could just type 'a' in the dialog over and over again. Eventually this would cause a Stack Overflow Error and your program would crash.

I would suggest using a loop.

```
while(true) {
    try{
        xValue = Integer.parseInt(value);
        break;
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Wrong input. Please input only integer values.");
    }
}
```

This way your program would just loop forever or until the user enters correct input instead of crashing. Unless you're implementing a recursive algorithm, I can't think of any reason for a method to invoke itself.